# Cannot get Aptana to recognize php includes

Tags: php, html, ide, aptana

I am trying to set up Aptana 3 to work on an html/css/js/php project that I'm currently using Dream Weaver to work on. It appears that the php is not being fully recognized or it's not set up correctly. For example for the line

```
<?php include_once "includes/header.php"; ?>
```

I am getting an error about missing a '>'

I first tried importing the project as a php project with "web" and "php" selected as natures.

I also tried creating a new php project and pasting in the files.

I also made sure the files are opening in the php editor.

Am I missing a key step to get Aptana set up for php?

Help much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: If you create a php file from scratch and put that line of code in, do you get the error?